# quarkus native image plugin (graalvm 20) crashes on windows 10 home (error 206): cannot run program, filename or extension too long

Tags: hibernate, windows-10, quarkus, graalvm-native-image, long-filenames

I can not successfully run "mvn package -Pnative" for a quarkus application on a windows 10 home machine. It fails with error "filename is to long". Any ideas anybody? I already acitvated long path names on windows regedit and gpedit ...

The command works for a "hello world" example, so I think the overall configuration is fine. The installed quarkus features are: agroal, cdi, hibernate-orm, jdbc-mysql, mutiny, narayana-jta, resteasy, resteasy-jsonb, security, security-jpa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known issue: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/2387

Here is a workaround: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/8850

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I'll look into this as soon as possible.

Comment: Puh, I have to admit that I do not understand what I would have to do to workaround my problem.

Thanx anyway!

Comment: Use the `<uberJar>` config for the quarkus-maven-plugin

Comment: <uberJar> seems to have solved my problem. Thanx a lot.